# DynamoDB table size

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I'm developing a DynamoDB table housing salary data by zip code.  Here's the structure of my table:

[image]

For a given zip code, there will be a Sort Key called Meta which houses lat/lon, city, state, county, etc.  In addition to Meta, I will have values in Sort Key for different sources of salary data for the given zip code.  Each value of salary data will be a JSON document.  I will have a lot of different data sources.  For example, there are around 41K zip codes and around 1100 ONET codes which equate to around 46 million rows, give or take - just for ONET data source type.

1. How many rows can a DynamoDB table efficiently handle?
2. Is there a better approach to structuring this data?

Thank you for your time.